# How can I get all questions asked by a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-questions

If anybody goes to http://www.facebook.com/questions he/she will be able to view all questions *answered* by him/her and all his/her friends.

I need to find all the questions that were *asked* by a Facebook page. Is the there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you're using Facebook as the page (click the down-pointing triangle in the top right-hand corner & select the page).
2. Scroll down to the page's publisher.
3. Select `Ask Question` - voilà!

**Update for Timeline.**

Pages that have Timeline enable (as of March-April 2012 - all pages) require a bit more work. Scroll down to the publisher, click on `Event, Milestone+`, and then select Question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just go to "Activity Log" on your facebook page, and than choose tab "question" and there you will see all the question that you asked. It is simple as that :)

Comment: If you spice it up with some screenshots, i'll upvote it !!